# difference between browser and script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my own *node.js* written in *C*. When I open the browser and browse to `192.168.0.150:8000/index` and call the script:

```
 var socket = io.connect("/index");

socket.on('connect', function() {
    $('#onindex').addClass('connected');
});
```

every thing is OK.
BUT:
When I try to:

```
       var socket = new io.Socket('192.168.0.150', {port: 8000 }); 
       socket.connect("/index.html");
```

I get the following error on the Javascript console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 192.168.0.150/index.html:80/socket.io/xhr-polling//…. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This indicates to me that the server can't find it.

How can I fake the JS to think I'm browsing?

Comment: What do you mean _your own node.js_? **Node.js** is node.js. You're either using node or your not...

Comment: I meant my own c implementation of WebSocket server.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're doing. It seems like you have a node.js server, then you connect a browser to that server as an HTTP client, and then a server-side script tries (unsuccessfully) to connect to the server itself as a client. Is my reading correct? Are there multiple servers involved here?

Comment: 10xs apsillers. The script is on an HTML page at the client side.

Comment: For clarification, what do you mean by '10xs'? In your first comment, I understood it to mean that you get the error message ten times, but after your latest comment to apsillers, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Greetings are discouraged. it's affects parsing performances of people trying to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your error message

> `XMLHttpRequest`

The problem was with *XMLHttpRequest* (on the side running the script)

> cannot load `192.168.0.150/index.html:80/socket.io/xhr-polling//`….

it couldn't load the page

> Origin `null` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

because it is **not allowed** to by **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** settings preventing an origin of `null`.

You can read up about [access control **here** on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). An origin of `null` can arise from a page located on a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) or using the `file:` protocol. This is part of the **same-origin policy** which you can read about [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You may have to set up CORS on your server to get it to work.

Comment: That may help for the Origin but the true problem is that I can't create a HTTP request on from the script that would be like the one from the browser